# Appending to Map with value as a list

Tags: scala

I have initialized a mutable `Map` (not sure if I should use a mutable here, but to start with I use mutable):

```
val aKey = "aa"
val myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]]()
if (myMap.exists(_._1 == aKey))
    myMap(aKey) = myMap.get(aKey) :: "test"
```

But on `myMap.get(aKey)` I get the following error:

> Type Mismatch expected List[String] actual option[String]

I thought the way I did is correct to append to list.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `myMap(aKey) = myMap.get(aKey) :: "test"`?

Comment: for a key in the map that is list of items append a new item to the list myMap.get(aKey) will return the list for the "aKey"

Comment: At the moment you are discarding items when the key doesn't already exist in the map. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 8):

You can append to a mutable map with `+=`.

```
scala> myMap += ("placeholders" -> List("foo", "bar", "baz"))
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(placeholders -> List(foo, bar, baz))
```

To append a new item to the list for `aKey` as mentioned in the commments.

```
myMap.get("placeholders") match {
 case Some(xs:List[String]) => myMap.update("placeholders", xs :+ "buzz")
 case None => myMap
}
res22: Any = ()

scala> myMap
res23: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(placeholders -> List(foo, bar, baz, buzz))
```

Comment: how do you add "zoo" to that list could you please show that

Comment: You answer didn't work when trying to append a single element to a list

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis I updated the answer based on your comment. The update gets "placeholders" from the map and if it exists the list of values is appended with "buzz".

Answer (score 6):

If you have [mutable Map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html) and inside that map [immutable List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html). This is a simple example on how to do it. The example is also defining using [withDefaultValue](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/Map.html#withDefaultValue(d:V):scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V]) - so that you always get something back from [Map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/Map.html).

```scala
var posts: collection.mutable.Map[Int, List[String]] = collection.mutable.Map().
  withDefaultValue List.empty[String]

def addTag(postID: Int, tag: String): Unit = posts.get(postID) match {
  case Some(xs: List[String]) => posts(postID) = xs :+ tag
  case None => posts(postID) = List(tag)
}

posts(42)
// List[String] = List() 

addTag(42, "tag-a")
addTag(42, "tag-b")
addTag(42, "tag-c")

posts(42)
// List[String] = List(tag-a, tag-b, tag-c)
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything is fine. Except for list append operator

To add an element to the list. The operator should be something like

```
myList = element :: myList
myList = myList :: element  // wrong
```

so your program should be

```
val aKey = "aa"
var myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]]().withDefaultValues(List())
myMap(aKey) = "test" :: myMap(aKey)
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you could alternatively use [`Map#updateWith`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#updateWith(key:K)(remappingFunction:Option[V]=%3EOption[V]):Option[V]) on mutable `Map`s (or [`Map#updatedWith`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#updatedWith[V1%3E:V](key:K)(remappingFunction:Option[V]=%3EOption[V1]):CC[K,V1]) on immutable `Map`s):

```
map.updateWith("a")({
  case Some(list) => Some("test" :: list)
  case None       => Some(List("test"))
})
```

> def updateWith(key: K)(remappingFunction: (Option[V]) => Option[V]): Option[V]

---

For instance,

```
val map = collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]]()
// map: collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]] = HashMap()
val key = "key"
// key: String = "key"
```

if the key doesn't exist:

```
map.updateWith(key)({ case Some(list) => Some("test" :: list) case None => Some(List("test")) })
// Option[List[String]] = Some(List("test"))
map
// collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]] = HashMap("key" -> List("test"))
```

and if the key exists:

```
map.updateWith(key)({ case Some(list) => Some("test2" :: list) case None => Some(List("test2")) })
// Option[List[String]] = Some(List("test2", "test"))
map
// collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]] = HashMap("key" -> List("test2", "test"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured the how to do it:

```
  val aKey = "aa"
  var myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]]()
  if (myMap.exists(_._1 == aKey))
    myMap.get(aKey).get :+ "foo"
  else {
    myMap(aKey) = List("zoo")
  }
```

This might not be the scala way of doing but this gives the correct results.

Comment: Using withDefaultValues makes it simpler

Answer (score 0):

first you shouldn't Mutable Map :). for add one item on List within Map, you can use method get of Map.

```
val m = Map(1 -> List(2))
val m2 = m.get(1).fold{
  // In this case don't exist any List for this key
  m + (1 -> List(3))
}{ list =>
  // In this case exist any List for this key
  m + (1 -> (3 :: list))
}
```